# Get current time from raspberry pi

Tags: esp32, raspberry-pi4, ntp

The challenge: I have a Raspberry Pi4 that is acting as a Hotspot and I have an ESP32-cam in the garden doing a time lapse. The Pi4 has no internet connection but it has a DS3231 RTC to keep current time. I would like to only take images in daylight hours and I need the ESP32-cam get the time from the Pi4 so that it knows when its daytime.

I am aware that NTP is the normal solution but as there is no internet connection I need the Pi4 to act as the NTP server. I have installed NTP on the Pi4 but I can't get it to serve the time to the ESP32. I have pointed the ESP32 at the Pi4 IP address but I just can't get the time from the Pi4.
I am not sure if this is possible and I am not experienced enough to get any further without help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Configure a local clock - `server 127.127.1.1 iburst prefer\n
fudge  127.127.1.1 stratum 8`. 2. Configure access permissions - `restrict -4 default notrap nomodify nopeer noquery` to allow exchange of time. 3. Start & check for errors. 4. Ensure the pi is takjing time from the ds3231. 5. You can get cheap GPS's with PPS which will give you micro or even nano second accuracy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I shall give it a try and update my progress either way.

Comment: I didn't like to say before but I didn't have a clue what your answer meant but after a bit of googling and trial and error I have managed to get it working. I have amazed myself! For the last week I have been getting nowhere with this because each time I searched I just got stuff about NTP in general. I just searched with your first line and got the correct responses. Thank again for your help.